# Beginning the deadlift exercise

Tags: bodybuilding, deadlifts

With so much misinformation all over the internet, how do I learn the Deadlift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Buy Mark Rippetoe's Starting Strength book and/or DVD to best learn the deadlift. As a preview, see [this collection of coaching videos](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/Deadlift_Videos), [this T-Nation deadlift overview](http://www.t-nation.com/readArticle.do?id=4952486), and/or [this CrossFit Journal article (PDF)](http://library.crossfit.com/free/pdf/51-2006_AnalysisofDeadlift.pdf).
2. Then, get a coach or friend who knows the deadlift well review your form. A powerlifting, Olympic lifting, or CrossFit gym would be a good place to look for coaching. This might cost money
3. Video yourself deadlifting and post it on Rip's forum or this site for a form check.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is Mark Rippetoe the ultimate source of knowledge on deadlift? Or is he up there with a few more good sources?

Comment: I would say that people other than Mark Rippetoe have also heard of, and can coach, the deadlift. But his book (and this process) is what I recommend.

Comment: An alternate route: review the summaries that answer [another Stack Exchange question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/what-is-the-correct-form-for-a-deadlift). They use Rippetoe and StrongLifts.